Quotients of triangle groups
I want to find all quotients of ordinary hyperbolic triangle group (2,3,8).
In general the "Triangle type" indicates the three positive integers p, q and r
in the defining presentation
 < x,y,z | xyz = x^8 = y^3 = z^2 = 1 >

Further I have  automorphisms R and S satisfying
R^8 = S^3 = (RS)^2 = 1

so <R,S> is a quotient of the ordinary (8, 3, 2) triangle group as defined above,
via a smooth epimorphism taking (x, y, z) to (R, S, RS).
Using GAP, I started:
LoadPackage("lins");

F := FreeGroup("x", "y", "z");;
x := F.1; y := F.2; z := F.3;;
G := F / [x^8, y^3, z^2, xyz];;
IsValidQuotient := function(G, H)
local Q, R, S, RS;
Q := G / H;
R := Q.1;
S := Q.2;
RS := R*S;
return (R^8 = One(Q)) and (S^3 = One(Q)) and (RS^2 = One(Q));
end;;

subgroups := LowIndexNormalSubs(G, 48);

quotients := [];

for H in subgroups do
if IsValidQuotient(G, H) then
Q := G / H;
 Add(quotients, Q);
 fi;
od;

for Q in quotients do
Print("Quotient Group: ", Q, "\n");
Print("Order: ", Size(Q), "\n");
od;

code founds 5 quotient groups, having presentation like
Quotient Group: Group( [ (1,4)(2,5)(3,6), (1,2,3)(4,6,5), (1,6)(2,4)(3,5) ] )
Order: 6

My question is: is it possible to print these quotient groups in the form of thier defining relators i.e x,y,z?

There is continuum of pairwise nonisomorphic quotient groups. How are you planning to print all these?

After finding the quotients, I need to make a check for reflexibility, which I am doing with this function:

Function to check for involutory automorphisms in the quotient
' HasInvolutoryAutomorphism := function(Q)
local auts, inv_auts, R, S, RS, i, aut, order, inv;
auts := AutomorphismGroup(Q);
inv_auts := [];
Find involutory automorphisms
for aut in Elements(auts) do
order := Order(aut);
if order = 2 then
Add(inv_auts, aut);
fi;
od;
R := Q.1;
S := Q.2;
RS := R*S; '

Check if any involutory automorphism inverts two of the generators
' for inv in inv_auts do
if ((Image(inv, R) = R^-1 and Image(inv, S) = S^-1) or
(Image(inv, R) = R^-1 and Image(inv, RS) = RS^-1) or
(Image(inv, S) = S^-1 and Image(inv, RS) = RS^-1)) then
return true;
fi;
od;
return false;
end;; '

and the code finds that out of 5 quotients, 3 have reflexibility. Now i want to print them and their presentation should look like this : ' [ x^2, y^3, x * y * z, z * y * x * z * y^-1 * z^-1 * x * z ] '.
